# What is the picture field in the node object?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

`print_r($node)` outputs:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [nid] => 4
    [type] => grouptype
    [language] => fa
    [uid] => 1
    ....
    [title] => sample group
    ....
    [name] => roshd
    [picture] => 
    ....
)
```

What is picture and how can I upload a picture into this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the profile picture of the author of that node. You can upload that in your edit profile form and you can display it using `theme('user_picture', $node);`.

If you want to be able to attach images to nodes, have a look at [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [ImageField.](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield).

Comment: tnx, I'm familiar with cck and imagefield.